# Time-sensitive WordPress Post Schedule

Tags: wordpress

TLDR: How to ensure no delay when using WP Post Schedule? When you schedule it at 12pm, it will be published at 12pm on the dot

I am creating a website for a virtual event. Programme itineraries for the event has been created as a CPT using ACF.

On the frontpage, there's a Live Feed section that shows 1 itinerary/post at a time. I use the WP Post Schedule built-in functionality for this purpose. What's happening now is that there is a delay of 20 seconds - 1 minute before these scheduled posts are actually published.

I already have a meta-refresh setup so I hope that helps WP to fire the cronjob without waiting on actual user visit.

I found [this](https://asharirfan.com/fix-delay-scheduled-post/) but unfortunately it's not working for me, the said #ss isn't present in #timestampdiv

**Current Situation**

I may have solved the issue above after getting 1 missed schedule earlier and on top of delayed scheduled posts (from 30sec-1min)

1. Installing Scheduled Post Trigger. I also added `is_page()` in the plugin's code.
2. Increasing memory limit in WP Config `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '500M');`
3. Changed `meta-refresh` time interval from 10 to 20

**Spoke too soon**

Pfft. 2pm post was delayed by 1min. Well, at least it's not a Missed Schedule. Gonna have to go back the drawing board. Probably trying

1. Add 3rd party "ping" service
2. Setup cron to run wp-cron every second. (Server config)

**Final Update**

Ditched the WP Cron / Scheduled Post and went with displaying post based on start time - end time instead. oh well!

Comment: I wish I knew how/where WP saved the "Seconds" field in scheduled post. That could be where the missing puzzle is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run scheduled tasks, WordPress uses a system called WP Cron. The main issue with WordPress cron and the cron scheduler is that wp-cron.php is only executed when a user visits your website and triggers a page load. This means that WordPress requires an HTTP/HTTPS request from your website to run scheduled tasks. The cron task is then queued to be executed.

Therefore its best to to add a server-side Cron trigger for wp-cron.php.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Event has started since 2 hours ago and already I am getting a Missed Schedule not just delayed Published post. I am looking at various ways to fix this now.

Comment: Great if you need any additinal help, let me know!

Comment: Ditched the WP Cron / Scheduled Post and went with display itinerary based on start time - end time instead. oh well!